# Trying to create a new item in list in c#

Tags: c#, json, list

I'm having a hard time to bind one particular field called **url** in a List.

This is my json format:

```
{
     id: 'someID',
     name: 'someName.pdf',
     url: { 
         download: 'https://mydomain/api_binary/v1/document/mcipv7sgq11c9e6e42upqapc7k '
         }
}
```

This is my model

```
public class CantoItem
{
    
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("default")]
    public DefaultNest Default { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public ResultUrl Url { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("tag")]
    public object Tag { get; set; }
    

}
public partial class ResultUrl
{
    [JsonProperty("preview")]
    public Uri Preview { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("download")]
    public Uri Download { get; set; }
   }

    [JsonProperty("tag")]
    public List<string> Tag { get; set; }

}
```

Then for adding the value I have:

```
    var cantoAssetMetadata = new List<CantoItem>();

                
foreach (JValue item in collection)
{
    try
    {
        var collectionjObj = JObject.Parse(item.ToString());            
        cantoAssetMetadata.Add(new CantoItem()
        {
            id = collectionjObj["id"].ToString(),
            name = collectionjObj["name"].ToString(),
            Url = collectionjObj["url"].ToString(),
            Tag = collectionjObj["tag"].ToString(),
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exeption: {ex}, {item}");
    }
}
```

Other fields are set correctly just the URL is not, I can´t figure out how I can set the value correctly. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You are calling `.ToString()` on a class object - `Url = collectionjObj["url"].ToString(),` `Url` is a `partial class` called `ResultUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following wouldn't work:

```
Url = collectionjObj["url"].ToString()
```

You will need to initialize the `Url` and set the related property:

```
name = collectionjObj["name"].ToString(),
Url = new ResultUrl()
          {
              Download = new System.Uri(collectionjObj["url"].ToString())
          },
Tag = collectionjObj["tag"].ToString(),
```

Comment: This is completely wrong, how this got marked as the accepted answer, I'll never know. You are taking a `class object` `.ToString()` and setting that to the Download property of a new `ResultUrl`. This wouldn't give you what you wanted.

Comment: @RyanWilson you are right, i also missed the fact it's a nested property, will delete my post

Comment: Just fix it and I'll be happy to remove my previous comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try

```
var cantoAssetMetadata = new List<CantoItem>();

                
foreach (JValue item in collection)
{
    try
    {
        cantoAssetMetadata.Add(item.ToObject<CantoItem>());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exeption: {ex}, {item}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.ToString()` on a class object - `Url = collectionjObj["url"].ToString(),` `Url` is a `partial class` called `ResultUrl`. Convert the `JToken` to the appropriate `class` which it `deserializes` to

```
//Convert to the proper class object type
Url = collectionjObj["url"].ToObject<ResultUrl>;
```